# Error while trying to add rows to JTable

Tags: java

I'm trying to add rows to my table whenever the user selects yes when they are asked to add the product to the cart or not with the help of JOptionPane Confirm Dialog.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Home {
final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;
JFrame window;

    public Home() {
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Home");
    window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Please select a book for more information", JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    Font plainFont = new Font("Serif", 0, 24);
    title.setFont(plainFont);
    title.setBounds(180, 230, 97, 29);

    //====================================================================//
    String [] bookStrings = {"[Select a book]", "The Host", "Ruby", "Divergent", "The Secret Garden", "Hunger Games"};
    JComboBox bookList = new JComboBox(bookStrings);
    //====================================================================//

    JLabel bookinfo = new JLabel();

    //====================================================================//
    JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    search.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);

    JButton cart = new JButton("Show Cart");
    search.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);

    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    search.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);

    JTable cartTable;
    String[] columns = {"Book Name","Author", "Quantity", "Price"};
    String [][] data = {};
    cartTable = new JTable(data, columns);
    cartTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 63));
    cartTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(cartTable);


    //====================================================================//

    search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            if (bookList.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "<html>Title: The Host <br> Author: Stephenie Meyer <br> Price: 110 AED <br> " +
                                "\n Synopsis: The Host is a romance novel by Stephenie Meyer. The book is about Earth, " +
                                "\n in a post apocalyptic time, being invaded by a parasitic alien race, known as \"Souls\", and " +
                                "\n follows one Soul's predicament when the consciousness of her human host refuses to co-operate " +
                                "\n with the takeover of her body."
                                + "\n \n Would you like to add this to cart?", "Book Details", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);


                if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    String [][] data = {{"The Host", "Stephenie Meyer", "2", "110"}};
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)(cartTable.getModel());
                    model.addRow(data);


                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE");
                }


        }
    });

    cart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Cart();
            window.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //====================================================================//

    JPanel panel;
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(title);

    panel.add(bookList);
    panel.add(search);
    panel.add(bookinfo);
    panel.add(cart);
    panel.add(exit);
    panel.add(jps);



    window.add(panel);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

However I'm getting this error: 
*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel*

Can someone help me with where I'm going wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
cartTable = new JTable(data, columns);
```

uses an anonymous AbstractTableModel if I remember correctly.

Use instead:

```
cartTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));
```

DefaultTableModel fires miscellaneous change events and handles dynamic data.